Does Stack Exchange have financial relationships with AI developers, allowing access to SE content for self-supervised training?
From a recent Economist article  https://www.economist.com/schools-brief/2024/07/23/ai-firms-will-soon-exhaust-most-of-the-internets-data?

Model capabilities can also be improved when the version produced by
self-supervised learning, known as the pre-trained version, is refined
through additional data in post-training. “Supervised fine-tuning”,
for example, involves feeding a model question-and-answer pairs
collected or handcrafted by humans. This teaches models what good
answers look like.


I looked for the answer on Meta StackExchange earlier and I didn't find it. It occurs to me now that if you also can't find the answer to this there then it might still be the better place to ask. Definitely more active.

This doesn't relate to the use of Space Exploration SE specifically - ask in the main meta or you can flag for moderator assistance to migrate this.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the use of of Space Exploration SE specifically. This question could in principle be posted on all of the almost 200 SE sites with equal relevance, which might be a record for the largest number of cross-posts. Instead, if posted anywhere at all, it should be in the main meta. I'm voting to close because it's not about the use of Space SE. There's always the possibility of migration after that, but you'd probably have to flag for a mod.

The question is not about Space Exploration "specifically". The fact it could be posted at other SE sites demonstrates its broad relevance. If SE members are laboring to provide training fodder for AI to the financial benefit of SE, they might like to know.

See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399619/our-partnership-with-openai

I'm going to vote to leave it open since if there were no other sites, this would be a suitable question. A mod can certainly migrate it to SE Meta - that might be an appropriate course of action.

VTCing since this belongs on main meta.
